# Android Universal image loader set wallpaper from url

Tags: android, image, loader, universal, setbackground

I tried to do the background with Universal image loader. But it did not
This is BaseActivity.java
Source Code: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader
How can I do wallpaper the selected image as background.
I know Selected image url's >> imageUrls2[pagerPosition]

BaseActivity.java

```
    //Copyright 2011-2013 Sergey Tarasevich
package com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.Constants.Extra;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

String[] imageUrls2;
protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_clear_memory_cache:
            imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
            return true;
        case R.id.item_clear_disc_cache:
            imageLoader.clearDiscCache();
            return true;
        case R.id.setBg: //Set Background Menu 

            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            imageUrls2 = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);

            int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imageUrls2[pagerPosition], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //For example http://www.wallpaperfx.com/view_image/abstract-glass-paint-1600x900-wallpaper-14862.jpg
            }
            return false;
}

}
```

ImageGalleryActivity.java

```
    package com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.Constants.Extra;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;

/**
 * @author Sergey Tarasevich (nostra13[at]gmail[dot]com)
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class ImageGalleryActivity extends BaseActivity {

    String[] imageUrls;

    DisplayImageOptions options;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_gallery);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageGalleryAdapter());
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startImagePagerActivity(position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startImagePagerActivity(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private class ImageGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageUrls.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            if (imageView == null) {
                imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_gallery_image, parent, false);
            }
            imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);
            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see imageview that you want to display. And try to clear your question

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a image gallery, select its item will go to Pager activity. But where do you want to display image? When select a option menu  in `onOptionsItemSelected`? Or in ImagePagerActivity?

Comment: I want to display on BaseActivity in onOptionsItemSelected
ScreenShot: (http://i.hizliresim.com/Jd44YY.png)

Comment: Because BaseActivity is abstract class, there is no view in it, so you can't display into it. I think you want to show image on sub class of BaseActivity, in this case it is ImagePagerActivity

Answer (score 0):

Base on your information, I think you can use protected method (or abstract method) on your base activity and override it in sub class activity (ImagePagerActivity). It look like this:

```
 public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item_clear_memory_cache:
                imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
                return true;
            case R.id.item_clear_disc_cache:
                imageLoader.clearDiscCache();
                return true;
            case R.id.setBg: //Set Background Menu 

                Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                imageUrls2 = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
                int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imageUrls2[pagerPosition], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // call protected method, subclass should override it
                displayImage(imageUrls2[pagerPosition]);    
                }
                return false;
    }

    protected void displayImage(String imageUrl){}
}

public class ImagePagerActivity extends BaseActivity{       
    @override
    public void displayImage(String imageUrl){
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, Your_Image_View);        
    }
}
```